# PersistentActor with PriorityMailbox?

Tags: akka, persistence

I would like to have an `PersistentActor` with a prioritized mailbox. When I follow [the documentation example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.1/scala/mailboxes.html#Mailbox_configuration_examples) and use and `UnboundedPriorityMailbox`, it does not fulfill the `PersistentActor`s `Stash` constraint of implementing  `DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics`.

Does a mailbox exist for my use case, should I try to implement my own, should I circumvent the problem by adding a normal actor with a PriorityMailbox before my `PersistentActor` or is there another pattern I am missing?